# How many principle primitive in ZFC set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I am reading both Paul Halmos **Naive Set theory** and Endertons **Elements of set theory**. Both the books are developing ZFC.

In Enderton, he says:

> Our axiom system begins with two primitive notions, the concepts of
> "**set**" and "**member**." In terms of these concepts we will define
> others, but the primitive notions remain undefined.

Whereas in Halmos book, he says:

> The principal concept of set theory, the one that in completely
> axiomatic studies is the principle primitive (undefined) concept, is
> that of **belonging**.

I think Enderton is correct as we never define the term set or member/belonging, so both of these must be the principle primitive. But searching on the Internet, it seems everyone agrees that only belonging/members is the principle primitive.

If so why isn't **Set** a principle primitive as well?

Comment: The basic concept is the relation "to be an element of" ($\in$). The relation is not symmetric: thus, we have two *relata*: the *element* that belongs to ab "object" and the object (the *set*) to which the element belongs.

Comment: See Luca Incurvati, [Conception of Set and the Foundations of Mathematics (2020, Cambridge University Press)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Conceptions_of_Set_and_the_Foundations_o/5InPDwAAQBAJ), page 2.

Comment: Form a formal point of view, the [language of set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/) has only one non logical primitive symbol: $\in$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I am reading the article you linked but it doesn't seem to clarify my doubts. Why are sets not among the principle primitives in ZF?